# SQL Server : list all columns used in queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to detect which columns and which tables are used in a SQL Server database?

- Just against SQL Server 2012 would be fine.
- We can assume there are no '*' for column usage in the legacy site.

**Details:**
I'm working on updating the table structure of a legacy system to work on a newer database (2005 to 2012)

There are a lot of bloated tables, with columns that are never used, and even tables that are never used. Identifying all of them would be a pain by manually going through the code.

(My assumption is that we can run SQL Server profiler while running a complete test pass on the app, but I don't know a convenient way to extract the columns)

Thanks.

Comment: It is ***very*** unlikely that you can take any columns or tables out without changing your code.  Tables and columns are generally only created to support some piece of code, so taking them out is likely to break that code.  There's no silver bullet for this situation.

Comment: @RBarryYoung BTW, your site seems to be down: Server Error in '/dnn' Application.

Comment: The legacy system is tied to multiple third party tools tied into the same data structure.  There are more than 100 tables, more than 2000 fields, and it seems like about half of the tables are entirely empty.    @RBarryYoung, while I agree that is how things should be built, in legacy it is rarely the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list dependencies for a table in Mgmt Studio, which will show you which SPs, UDFs etc depend on the table in question. You can't do that for a single field. However, that would only show the internal dependencies.  Sql Profiler would theoretically show you all fields that get requested by your app however it still would not really tell you much as the app may not do anything with the values it retrieves. If you are going to change the db it would only really make sense to put in the effort if you were also going to change the app and then you should be really get some input from users on what features are still useful and what is broken before you get too involved in a back-end refresh. IMHO.

Comment: I'll probably accept this as the answer, because I don't see a way to do it either.  *Theoretically*, a full test suite should be utilizing every part of the application, and every part of the database.  Unfortunately, much of the SQL code is actually in the application, not just sprocs & other objects internal to the DB.  I'm assuming this is the best answer, but I'll leave this open to give the opportunity for a potential 'yes it can be done, here's how'